# Program to Translate Turing Machine to Tableau?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, boolean-algebra

Is a program available to translate a [Turing Machine program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) to [Boolean tableau format](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~knowak/cs525_winter_2016_e/The_Cook_Levin_Theorem.pdf) as used for example in proofs of the Cook-Levin theorem?

Comment: Requests for code are generally off-topic here.  If you understand the proof you should be able to implement it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @D.W. – I've implemented Cook-Levin translations before, it's a bit tedious but not terribly difficult. Rather than trying to find an existing program that can handle exactly your desired input and output formats, I would suggest you just implement one yourself. I would make an exception if you were looking for a program that produces _size-optimized_ Boolean formulas, which is a rather more complicated problem related to oblivious Turing machines.